# CTC loss incorrect computation

Tags: python, tensorflow, ctc

Python's input:

```
sequence1 = [0, 1] 
output1 = [[1, 0, 0],[0, 1, 0]]
loss = tf.compat.v1.nn.ctc_loss(
                               labels=tf.sparse.from_dense([sequence1]),
                               inputs=np.array([output1]).astype('float32'),
                               sequence_length=[2],
                               time_major = False
                               )
print(loss.numpy())
```

Python's output:

```
array([1.2408944], dtype=float32)
```

Mathematica's input:

```
CTCLossLayer[<|
   "Input" -> {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}, 
   "Target" -> {1, 2} (* Index starts from 1 and not 0 *)
|>]
```

Mathematica's output:

```
0.
```

Since my sequence is `[0,1]` and it's one hot encoding (when number of characters is 2 + 1(for CTC)) is `[[1,0,0],[0,1,0]]` - shouldn't the `nn.ctc_loss` be `0`? As in Mathematica? Thanks!